# Change UITableView row culling behavior?

Tags: uitableview, swift

Is it possible to change the behaviour of tableview row culling?

For instance, change it so that it doesn't remove/destroy cells unless they are at least 4 rows off screen (in either direction) ?

So to visualize this:

```
-- Row 1
-- Row 2
-- Row 3
-- Table view visible top here. Any rows above are off screen
-- Row 4
-- Row 5
```

So in this scenario, imagine that the default behaviour is to cull/destroy rows as soon as they leave the visible screen area. So in this case, row's 1>3 would be destroyed and recreated as they come back onto the screen.

This can result in some visual hiccups, depending on how you are gathering data and how much is being displayed in the cells etc.

So to make the row recreation less obvious on the eye, i would like to higher the limit, to only cull rows after they move up either x amount of rows above the table view top, or after a row is y amount of pixels above (i.e not visible) the cut off point.

Comment: describe more and post the code what you have tried?

Comment: I haven't tried anything in particular, as i have searched online with various terms and cannot find any info on the subject. Can you really expect someone to try something with nothing to go on whatsoever ?